# Animating Glyphicon on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to animate a `glyphicon-refresh` icon so that when I click on the icon it should rotate. I am trying to do this using CSS3, but it is not working properly.

Here is my markup:

```
<a id="update" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></a>
```

Here is my css:

```
<style>

.glyphicon-refresh-animate {
  animation-name: rotateThis;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes "rotateThis" {
 from { transform: scale( 1 ) rotate( 0deg );   }
 to   { transform: scale( 1 ) rotate( 360deg ); }
}

</style>
```

Here is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( "#update" ).on( "click", function( e ) {
            var $icon = $( this ).find( ".glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" ),
            animateClass = "glyphicon-refresh-animate";

            $icon.addClass( animateClass );
            // setTimeout is to indicate some async operation
            window.setTimeout( function() {
                $icon.removeClass( animateClass );
            }, 2000 );
        });    
    });
</script>
```

Any help, or an alternative approach, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First: Your jQuery selector is wrong:

```
.glyphicon glyphicon-refresh
```

has to be

```
.glyphicon.glyphicon-refresh
```

Second: You should prefix all `animate` properties, the `keyframes` keyword and the `transform` property with vendor prefixes. (Only Firefox and IE10+ support without prefix. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) For example for Safari and Chrome:

```
.glyphicon-refresh-animate {
   -webkit-animation-name: rotateThis;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes "rotateThis" {
 from { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate( 0deg );  
    }
 to  { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate( 360deg ); 
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DX4AJ/ This fiddle only works in Safari and Chrome!

Comment: Thank u , but I am using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If allowed using [fontawsome](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/style/animate), there is an out-of-box solution with the `fa-spin` class.